# Diablo III, I need to be at "X" level to drop this legendary item?

Tags: diablo-iii

I would like to try to drop a [Puzzle Ring](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/puzzle-ring) which is a level 29 ring.

I'm afraid of **Diablo III** levelling system and it's relative things 'cause I know that a player on level **20** only can drop equipment around **1** level down/up of the current player level, but happens the same for the legendary items? then that means I need to be at level **28** (as minimum) or at level **30** (as maximum) to drop my desired ring?.

And please, I dont would like to ask two questions in the same post but someone could tell me where to drop that ring?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Level 29 is only the minimal required level at which the Puzzle Ring can drop, it drops with the level you have when it drops (and gets better with every level higher).
2. Most legendaries (including the puzzle ring) can drop in every form of game (story, adventure) from every mob (normal mobs, rare, boss) and also from chests and other items.